# uiwebview without interface builder

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsurl

I've to switch a part of my app: I will implement a web view insread of a picture (imageview).

So I tried to make it with the interface builder but there is too many errors so I prefer to use code!

for the pictures, I user those lines :

```
image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,64,320,367);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[self.imageView release];
```

Now, I tried to use this code but nothing's showed:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

...

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.fr"]]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

If you know how to make .... would be nice for me,

THANKS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare in your h file:

```
UIWebView *contentWebView;
```

And also tell to your viewController that you will implement `<UIWebViewDelegate>`

In viewDidLoad Add:

```
    contentWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    contentWebView.delegate = self;
    contentWebView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    contentWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;    
    [self.view addSubview:contentWebView];
```

In dealloc don't forget to release the webView:

```
[contentWebView release];
```

And implement the delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark WebViewDelegates

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{   


}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{  

}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{

}
```

And also you need to load an request. You can doit in viewDidLoad after you have added the webView to your view:

```
[contentWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"]]];
```

Comment: @Terente : OK, big thanks but the "webViewDidStartLoad:" is loading directly, nothing appears and the program crash!

Comment: Where did you load the request? I just made an test and all is working fine.

Comment: What is the line that crashes? What is the console output?

Comment: hum... there was a NSLog("xxx); instead of @"xxx" ... huhum thanks :D

Comment: @Terente : Re, I HAD a TabBar before and the UIWebView hide it... How can i Make to resize the webview exactly the height & width of the rest of the screen???

Comment: Iphone UI heights: Status Bar: 20px
Navigation Bar: 44px
Tab Bar: 50px  You only need to substract the height of ui from height of the screen

Answer (score 1):

adjust the frame as u needed and if add anything like imageview as subview to webview then u have to use bringsubviewtofront function.

```
        - (void) initUIWebView {
            NSLog(@"DetailViewController->initUIWebView {");

                UIWebView *aWebView;

                    //  init and create the UIWebView
                aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
                aWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
                aWebView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

                    //set the web view delegates for the web view to be itself
                [aWebView setDelegate:self];

                    //Set the URL to go to for your UIWebView
                NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;

                    //Create a URL object.
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

                    //URL Requst Object
                NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

                    //load the URL into the web view.
                [aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

                    //add the web view to the content view
                [self.view addSubview:aWebView];

                [aWebView release], aWebView = nil;

            }

              - (void)viewDidLoad {

                  [self initUIWebView]; // <<<<<<<<<<<< this calls the UIWebView Function
                  [super viewDidLoad];

              }
```

Comment: WORK! ;-) THAAAAAAANKS ! Can you say me how activate the gestures (is there a way to block the view (to permit the "swipe") ?

Comment: @madhu : Re, I HAD a TabBar before and the UIWebView hide it... How can i Make to resize the webview exactly the height & width of the rest of the screen???

Comment: aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 22, 320, 400)];change this to 22

Comment: @madhu : Thanks. I already tried this but it doesn't working :-o